# swift, mapView, annotation view wont show upon tap

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I implemented map view and created simple data model for annotations.

The pins are shown on the map, but I am still unable to get the details by tapping any pin.

[image: pins screenshot]

My Code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var topView: MapDataView!

    var dummyModel: DummyModel?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dummyModel = DummyModel()

        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(mapView.userLocation.coordinate, 1000, 1000)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        let range = 0..<Int((dummyModel?.objectsArray.count)!)
```

Array is valid and has no nil:

```
        for i in range {
            mapView.addAnnotation((dummyModel?.objectsArray[i])!)
        }
```

The way i add annotation to the map:

```
        mapView.selectAnnotation(mapView.annotations[0], animated: true)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        print("viewForAnnotation")
        let identifier = "PubMapObject"

        if annotation is PubMapObject {
            var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

            if annotationView == nil {
                annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
                annotationView!.canShowCallout = true

                let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
                annotationView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
            } else {
                annotationView!.annotation = annotation
            }

            return annotationView
        }

        return nil
    }
```

This method never called and i dont know why. i guess the problem is here, but i am unable to find it ):

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        print("annotationView")
        let pub = view.annotation as! PubMapObject
    }        
}
```

Comment: update your full code , as i think didSelect method and other method is missing in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add set frame of annotation view before returning annotation view
//my annotation class and provide width and height to annotation view before returning the annotation view and give frame to

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

if (annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self)) {
            return nil
        }


 let reuseId = "PubMapObject"
        if (annotation.isKind(of: PubMapObject.self)) {
            let anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            anView.isEnabled = true
            anView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
          let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
           btn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 70)
            anView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
            anView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 70)
             return anView
         }

  return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using didSelect function instead of calloutAccessoryControlTapped.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect annotationView: MKAnnotationView) { ...
```